# Why Text box size increases automatically during runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I am making a facebook like login page. in it im using 2 inline text boxes just like facebook front page. things were going good but automatically the size of both the textbox increases at runtime. i don't know what had happened as i already told you that things were going good

```
<div class=" form-group form-inline">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbSName" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname"></asp:TextBox>
                        <div class="form-group form-inline">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Enter Valid First Name" ForeColor="Red" Style="font-size: small" ControlToValidate="tbName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSname" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Enter Valid Surname" ForeColor="Red" Style="font-size: small; padding:60px;" ControlToValidate="tbSName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

also i m using bootstrap to make it responsive and in small screens it's working well but not on large screens

see the image [click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOXd2.jpg)

Please help

Comment: all the other textboxes are well formated

Answer (score 0):

your bootstrap css is applied later. when you run the page in browser initially the css is NOT applied but when the css is loaded the textbox sizes increases which is the correct style of the selected class in bootstrap css. Try using ur inspect element of browser and remove the class attribute, you will get back ur initially loaded textboxes style

Comment: form-control class?

Comment: yes, what it changes to is the style of your `form-control-class`

Comment: i can't remove that class it's necessary

Comment: "things were going good but automatically the size of both the textbox increases at runtime". just check it, it will make sure what you see later is the real small sized css style of textboxes which you wanted.

Comment: i have checked it applied padding also with size but all in vain